# Why is the mouth of the horn for ultrasonic air transducer narrower than the throat?

Tags: acoustics

Generally, the mouth of an acoustic horn is wider than the throat. However, most of the horns for ultrasonic air transducers are reversed. what is this aimed at?

Answer (score 1):

Those transducers are not for use in air, they are for use in ultrasonic welding machines. the horn is tapered and tuned to put a displacement maximum at the end of the aluminum horn, to properly drive the welding shoe.

Comment: thank for your clear answer.